# What is this "Jacobi method" of orthogonalization of bilinear forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

In Shilov's *Linear Algebra* he gives ($\S$7.5) a method for orthogonalization of a symmetric bilinear form (or if you prefer, a quadratic form) which he calls **Jacobi's method**. In his terminology, the problem is finding a **canonical basis** for the bilinear form, such that the matrix of the form is diagonal. The only reference I've been able to find outside of Shilov is from [the Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Jacobi_method), which cites another Russian text. This isn't common terminology in the Western world, but a very similar method appears to be the Gram-Schmidt process, though I haven't looked into it as closely, and it applies particularly to Euclidean space and obtains orthonormalization.

The problem is essentially this, in Shilov's terminology. Given a nonsingular symmetric bilinear form $A(x,y)$ acting in a linear space $\mathbf{K}_n$ of dimension $n$ (finite) over a field $K$, and given an arbitrary basis $\{e\} = e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$, such that $A(e_i,e_j) = A(e_j,e_i)$ for all $i,j$, find a transformation to a new basis $\{f\}=f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ such that $A(f_i,f_j)=0$ when $i\neq j$, and $A(e_i,e_i) = \lambda_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is called a **canonical coefficient**. The basis $\{f\}$ is called a **canonical basis** of the bilinear form $A(x,y)$.

This problem can be solved by induction, but we wish to find a method such that "the components of the vectors of the canonical basis and the corresponding canonical coefficients $\lambda_i$ [are able] to be determined directly from a knowledge of the elements of the matrix $A_{(f)}$," for $A_{(f)}$ is the matrix of $A(x,y)$ in the basis $\{f\}$. The required method, Shilov goes on to say, is *Jacobi's method*, as described in the Encyclopedia article above.

How is this method presented in modern literature? What terminology does it goes by?

Answer (score 0):

Let q be a quadratic form on a space V, represented in a basis $(\vec e_1, ... , \vec e_n)$ by the matrix A, namely
$$q(\vec x) = \vec x^t A \vec x$$
Then, Jacobi's method implies that in some basis $(\vec b_1,...,\vec b_n)$, q is diagonal, and for any $\vec x = x'_1\vec b_1+...+x'_n \vec b_n \in V$
$$q(\vec x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\Delta _{i-1}}{\Delta_i} (x_i')^2$$
where $\Delta_i$ is the leading priciple minor.

such a basis are not unique

The proof is constructive, I will provide it later.

Comment: Thanks @Irvingo, but be sure to read the full question before answering. It's clear what Jacobi's method is and how it works (and is proven) but the question I have is, what is the common terminology for this, as "Jacobi's Method" is only used in Russian/Soviet textbooks.